# Finding the boundary of a set given by inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, geometry, analysis

Let $f_1, \ldots f_m:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be continuous, and suppose the set $E$ is given by $$E=\{ x \in \mathbb R^n: \forall i,f_i(x) \ge0 \}$$

Is it true that $$ \partial E=\{x \in \mathbb R^n: \forall i, f_i(x)=0 \} $$?

Another question: Under what reasonable conditions for  the functions is it true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some inequalities might be redundant and then with equalities you would get a contradiction. For example, set

$$ E = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x \geq 0, x-1 \geq 0\},$$

then $$\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x = 0, x -1 = 0\} = \varnothing.$$

I hope this helps ;-)

Comment: For what functions $f$'s will it be true?

Comment: @MichaelTouitou Right now, I don't know. However, I would make a different definition, that is $$\partial E = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \exists k.\ f_k(x) = 0 \land \forall i \neq k.\ f_i(x) \geq 0\}.$$

Answer (score 3):

No, let $m=1$, $f_1 \ge 0$ have bounded support.  Then $E$ has no boundary, but $\{f_1 = 0\}$ has a bunch of points in it.